# Which angle should it be?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

in the formula

$$dB = \frac{\mu_0l ~|dl \times r|}{4 \pi r^3} $$

and the image
[image]

where dl is in y-z plane and dB is in x-y plane. the ring conductor is in y-z plane carrying current I in direction as mentioned
**EDIT**: also point p can move in the circular ring

**EDIT 2**:To clear the confusion...The dl vector is having (L alphabet) and current is I (i alphabet).

I want to know that is the angle between dl and r is 'Theta' ? how?

Comment: are you claiming that $\theta$ is the angle between $dI$ and $r$?

Comment: No, but I want to confirm that...because it is given in my text book and i cannot understand how ?

Comment: is $dI$ parallel to z-axis and perpendicular to y-axis?

Comment: No, not always because point p is arbitrary point on that circular conductor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angle between $dl$ and $r$ at any point on the circular loop is $90^0$. Look at the below figure.
[image]

Comment: Which software is used to make such figures?

Answer (score 1):

The angle between $\vec {dl}$ and $\vec r$ is $2n\pi \pm\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ because the angle between them is the angle between the x-r plane and y-z plane.

Comment: Please reconsider the question

Comment: The vector r only stays in x-y plain in two cases in rest cases the vector shifts away(in four octants of graph where x is positive) hence the angle is not what you are saying

Comment: The point p is not on y-axis but is on the circle (arbitrary).That is why the angle is not (never) a constant but a variable

Comment: @Mukul It can be mathematically proved by using 3-D geometry that the angle b/w $\vec {dl}$ and $\vec r⃗ $ is ${90}^0$(angle in principle range) whatsoever be the position of p on the circle defined by $y^2+z^2=R^2$. I got to go now to sleep. Post your answer on Math.SE

Comment: I understood now.Looks like I got a problem of 3D imagination.

Comment: @MukulKumar Ask for a mathematical prove in your question. you will get a nice answer. Btw choose the most appropriate anwser as accepted cya.

Answer (score 1):

the angle between $dl$ and $r$ is $\pi/2$, which is *not* $\theta$.

$\theta$ is the angle between $r$ and y-z plane. if you know what is $x$ and $r$, then $\sin\theta=x/r$, where $x$ is the distance from the origin to the point of intersection of $r$ and x-axis, and $r$ is the distance from p point to the same place

UPDATE.
$\theta$ is important because your $dB$ is at this angle to x-axis. so when you add up all $dB$ resulting from all points p, only the $\cos\theta dB$ parts will contribute, because the part of $dB$ which is in y-z plan will cancel each other. for each point p, there's is an opposite point on the ring, they cancel each other's $dB$ on y-z plane, but not on x-axis. that's why resulting $B$ will be on x-axis.

Comment: So, according to you x/r is constant ? let me update the image

Comment: what do you mean by constant? it is constant regardless which point p you choose. it is _not_ constant with regards to which point on x-axis you're considering

Comment: Fix this answer because the angle is (pie)/2 and not (pie)/4

Comment: @MukulKumar, good catch

Comment: $\pi$ is 180, so 90 is $\pi/2$